# How can I change parent div based on a class of nested element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parent-child

I would like to adjust my image-slide container, based on width of the image, so the adjusting would happen only if the height is bigger than width, here's what I have so far:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var imgs = $('.swiper-slide-image');
  imgs.each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    var width = img.width();
    var height = img.height();
    if (width < height) {
      img.addClass('portrait');
    } else {
      img.addClass('landscape');
    }
  })
});
```

This works well, I get "portrait" class whenever the height is bigger than width.

I would like to perform changes only, when "portrait" class is present.
The html looks like this:

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <figure class="swiper-slide-inner">
    <img class="swiper-slide-image portrait" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

I need to target `div.swiper-slide` - I only need to add special class to it.

I have tried following:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.swiper-slide-image').each(function() {
    var imgs = $('.swiper-slide-image');
    if ((img).hasClass("portrait")) {
      (this).parents('.swiper-slide').addClass('special-one');
    }
  })
});
```

but with no result :/

Will appreciate any help with this one!

Many thanks

Comment: You are missing `$` here: `('.swiper-slide-image').each(function()`. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes that was a typo - edited now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `$` two times and also to put `img` into quotes in the jQuery selector:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.swiper-slide-image').each(function() {
    var imgs = $('.swiper-slide-image');
    if ($('img').hasClass("portrait")) {
      $(this).parents('.swiper-slide').addClass('special-one');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.special-one {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <figure class="swiper-slide-inner">
    <img class="swiper-slide-image portrait" / src="https://placehold.it/300x200/b9a">
  </figure>
</div>
```